# Polymer create element dynamically

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I need to create an custom-element dynamically.

I tried

```
var newElement= document.createElement('custom-element');
```

this is work. but My problem is when I want to add attribute to this element, to bind an array to this element. 
I tried

```
newElement.setAttribute('data','{{data}}')
```

But it says that it expected to array and received '{{data}}'

How can I add this binding to dynamically elements?

Comment: Why do you need it that way? Maybe if you give more details of what you want to achieve someone could give you an alternative.

Comment: I want to render an element, To be like it was when the page loaded

Comment: Not sure i understand, but you can set the object properties (not the attributes directly) and using reflectToAttribute you can manage your component state without trying to dynamically set a binding expression like you are trying to do.

Comment: I know that. But after some changes was in the element this is little difficult to  reset every field.I use swipe-pages that make css transition and if I will try to reset every value I will have to calculate the changes in the transition,  maybe it the right solution  but it a lot of work for nothing (300 milisec for render?)
 Then I thought to  remove the element and add it again.Thus I will not have mistake in calculations and forget to reset something.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible right now, please see from kevinpschaaf:

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1778

> No, we don't currently support this, outside of dom-bind, which is the
>   only template implementation that late-binds instance children. You
>   can document.createElement('template', 'dom-bind'), then you can
>   dynamically append children with binding annotations to its content,
>   and the bindings will only be evaluated once the dom-bind is attached
>   to the document. See tests here that show this usage of it:
>   https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/test/unit/dom-bind.html#L95
>
> Note that dom-bind does not currently allow binding to outer scope, so
>   it has limited use in custom element templates (it's main use case is
>   for binding between elements in the main document), and that's not
>   likely to change short-term.
>
> We are achieving a lot of performance optimization by baking the
>   binding connections into the prototype at registration time for an
>   element (rather than at instance time), and we haven't built up enough
>   of the machinery to easily allow runtime addition/removal of bindings.